# mysql query for finding the distance with in a radius in miles

Tags: mysql

I have a query for finding the distance in kilometer within a radius

```
SELECT id,first_name,avatar,user_des,thirdparty_account_type,user_latitude,user_longitude,last_login_time,SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( user_latitude - 13.00887806598545) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( 77.65931731975401 - user_longitude ) * COS( user_latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance FROM ls_users  ORDER BY distance ASC limit 0,40
```

The distance iam getting is in Kilometer.How i can convert it into miles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 kilometer = 0.621371192 miles. Just multiply the distance with that constant.

```
SELECT id,first_name,avatar,user_des,thirdparty_account_type,
    user_latitude,user_longitude,last_login_time,
    SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( user_latitude - 13.00887806598545) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( 77.65931731975401 - user_longitude ) * COS( user_latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) * 0.621371192 AS distance
FROM ls_users
ORDER BY distance ASC limit 0,40
```